Is there a better way to create a time series?
GFY2018 = pd.date_range("10-01-2017", "9-30-2018")
GFY2019 = pd.date_range("10-01-2018", "9-30-2019")
GFY2020 = pd.date_range("10-01-2019", "9-30-2020")
GFY2021 = pd.date_range("10-01-2020", "9-30-2021")
GFY2022 = pd.date_range("10-01-2021", "9-30-2022")
GFY2023 = pd.date_range("10-01-2022", "9-30-2023")
GFY2024 = pd.date_range("10-01-2023", "9-30-2024")
GFY2025 = pd.date_range("10-01-2024", "9-30-2025")

Is there a better way to write this? Plan is to parse these through a dataset and create a new column based on if the create date is within a range.
Thank You!

Don't, use a container: years = {y: pd.date_range(f"10-01-{y-1}", f"9-30-{y}") for y in range(2018,2026)} ; then years[2018] to access a particular series.
